# Hive: how to select from specfic sub-partiton

Tags: hive, hiveql

For example, create a table in hive.

```
CREATE TABLE t_data_daily(
    imp_date BIGINT,
    sp STRING,
    datax STRING
)
PARTITION BY LIST( imp_date )
SUBPARTITION BY LIST( sp )(
    SUBPARTITION sp_1 VALUES IN ( 'sp_1' ),
    SUBPARTITION sp_2 VALUES IN ( 'sp_2' ),
    SUBPARTITION sp_3 VALUES IN ( 'sp_3' )
)
(
    PARTITION p_20191030 VALUES IN ( 20191030 ),
    PARTITION p_20191101 VALUES IN ( 20191101 ),
    PARTITION p_20191122 VALUES IN ( 20191122 )
)
```

select data with specific partition:

```
select * from t_data_daily partition (p_20191030) x limit 100
```

How to select data from specific partition and sub-partition?
Except the following：

```
select * from t_data_daily partition (p_20191030) x where sp = 'sp_1' limit 100
```

Comment: Such create table statement will not work in Hive

Comment: @leftjoin I fix it.